# Use a JS <script> just in one razor page

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side

Using blazor and .Net 5, I need to know is it possible to use a `.js` file just inside an specific razor page?

More info: I careated a simple script and saved it to a file `MyJavaScript.js`:

```
function myfunction()
  {
    alert("Hello");
  }
```

then added it to _host.cshtml:

```
<script src="/MyJavaScript.js"></script>
```

Now when I type `localhost:1212` or `localhost:1212/counter` or other razor pages, it loads the `.js` file at first visit to the browser and switched between pages, all the razor pages  in my web app, know the `.js` file and I can use `IJSRuntime` to invoke `myfunction` in all razor pages. I want to know if I can have a specific `.js` file just limited/specialized for `mypage.razor` page and not public to all my razor pages. Is that possible?

In the other hand, I want only address `localhost:1212/mypage`  show the alert and know `myfunction` and not all the razor pages. So wherre should I put the `MyJavaScript.js` file?

Update 1: apparently, we can not put `<script></script>` tag inside a component.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Put it only where you need it to be. To be more detail, put it in `mypage.razor` only.

Comment: Simply, name the function in a different way, and call it only inside of mypage.razor.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Chaeck update 1 above. Apparently, we can not put <script></script> tag inside a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like from your screen cap you're almost there - you need to [import the js module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules-1) via `IJSRuntime` and then invoke the function as normal via the `IJSObjectReference`. Make sure your js file function has the `export` keyword.

I'm pulling this from the docs in the link above for easier reference, but for .NET 5, this looks like this:

```
// wwwroot/scripts.js
export function showPrompt(message) {
  return prompt(message, 'Type anything here');
}
```

```
@page "/call-js-example-6"
@implements IAsyncDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1>Call JS Example 6</h1>

<p>
    <button @onclick="TriggerPrompt">Trigger browser window prompt</button>
</p>

<p>
    @result
</p>

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference module;
    private string result;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", 
                "./scripts.js");
        }
    }

    private async Task TriggerPrompt()
    {
        result = await Prompt("Provide some text");
    }

    public async ValueTask<string> Prompt(string message)
    {
        return await module.InvokeAsync<string>("showPrompt", message);
    }

    async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (module is not null)
        {
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```